# Wine applications have no sound after moving drive_c folder

Tags: sound, wine

I moved the drive_c of Wine to another partition. Now everything is good except sound. Wine applications no longer have sound. What's the problem?

**Edit:**

The main problem (I think) is that I have deleted all config text files in `/home/[user-name]/.wine` Then `wine` created new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Run `winecfg` and go to the audio tab then click OK (you don't have to do anything, wine configure audio automatically when you open that tab)